# How to invert a range

Tags: numbers, range

I have a range of values from 0 to 100, and I want to have the values inverted (ex. 100->0,0->100, 25->75, etc)
How would I do this? (in any language)

Comment: can you please provide a more clear example

Comment: I think the question is confusingly written, but a few more examples make it more clear. If I understand correctly, you'd like a function which, for example, returns: `invert(100) == 0`, `invert(0) == 100`, `invert(25) == 75`, `invert(70) == 30`, `invert(50) == 50`, etc.

Comment: This is, of course, **assuming** that the "inversion" is within the range 0-100, and you're not concerned about how to handle bad input like `invert(101)`.

Comment: I am not concerned about bad input, because the range is generated by normalizing a list to a range of 0-100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each `value`, do `100 - value`.

Note:
A general function for a range `(min, max)` would be:

```
invert(min, max, value)
  => max - value + min;
```